# Is a continuous function $ f\colon(0,\infty)\to R$, such that $f(x)\leq f(nx)$ increasing?

Tags: calculus, limits

My question is related to: 
[LeL $f: (0, \infty)\to R$ be continuous and $f(x)\leq f(nx)$ prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576542/lel-f-0-infty-to-r-be-continuous-and-fx-leq-fnx-prove-lim-limits)
and
[$f\colon(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ be continuous ; $f(x)\le f(nx) , \forall n \in \mathbb N , \forall x >0$ , then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063430/f-colon0-infty-to-mathbb-r-be-continuous-fx-le-fnx-forall-n-in)

Let $f\colon (0, \infty)\to R$ be  continuous such that  $f(x)\leq f(nx)$ for all positive $x$ and natural $n$.

It was proved that the limit (finite or infinite) in the infinity exists.
Do we know if such a function must be (weakly) increasing?
I believe that there might be counterexamples.

Comment: The fact that **infinite limit** exists is a weird (i.e. mathematical) way to say: there is no limit. In other words, it means that a sequence not bound to any concrete value.

Comment: @52heartz From the topological point of view it is pretty natural definition.

Comment: @52heartz it just another way to say that $\sup f(x)$ and $\inf f(x)$ are equal when taking the limit

Answer (score 5):

Let
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x \quad &\text{if}  \quad x\leq 1\\
2-x \quad &\text{if} \quad 1\leq x \leq 4/3\\
x- 2/3 \quad &\text{if} \quad x\geq 4/3
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

In $[1,4/3]$, $f(x)$ has minimum  $2/3$, and in $[1/2,2/3]$, it has maximum $2/3$. Hence satisfies the condition.
Other regions also satisfies the condition. It is also continuous.

[image: Plot of function]

Comment: Thank you for comment. Legend was not reversed but I was plotting $f(x/2)$ and $f(x/3)$, not $f(2x)$ and $f(3x)$. I fixed it. Function is not increasing on $[1,4/3]$. @uniquesolution

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a counterexample to the claim, hence a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $f(x)$ such that:
$f(x)=10^x$ for $x \in [0,10]$

$f(x)=10^{10}-(x-10)^{100}$ for $x\in [10,11]$

$f(x)=10^{10}-1+10^{10}\times (x-11)$ for $x>11$

Comment: Is this a counter-example? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this and the answer is **no**, I'll edit my answer in the other question, thank you for letting me know for my mistake. The function:

We will define $[x]=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if}&[x]=0\\
f(\lfloor x\rfloor)-2[x]&\text{if}&[x]\in(0,0.5)\\
f(\lfloor x\rfloor)+2[x]&\text{if}&[x]\in[0.5,1)\end{cases}$$

Comment: Your answer for the previous question really needs editing or deleting. All you proof was based on the assumption, that $f$ is (weakly) increasing.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I edit it, I said it was wrong and link to here