# A continues non-increasing function satisfying $f(x)\leq f(2x)$ for all $0\leq x$

Tags: calculus

Is there a **continues** function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ satisfying $f(x)\leq f(2x)$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$ which is **not** increasing in $[0,\infty)$?

EDIT: In "increasing" I mean in the broader sense, that is $x<y$ implies $f(x)≤f(y)$

Thanks!

Comment: Any increasing function satisfies $f(x) \leq f(2x)$ for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: sorry, i meant non-increasing function...

Comment: Then you are seeking to satisfy both "$\leqslant$" and "$\geqslant$" at the same time. Just how can that be done?

Comment: Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=1$

Comment: In "increasing" I mean $x<y$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$, so non increasing,  if there exist $x<y$ such that $f(x)>f(y)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a continuous function $ f\colon(0,\infty)\to R$, such that $f(x)\leq f(nx)$ increasing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576594/is-a-continuous-function-f-colon0-infty-to-r-such-that-fx-leq-fnx-i)